# REST API call Orderby - JSON changes my order!

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, json, sharepoint-framework

So the below function, gets data from a list in a certain order - by SortOrder column. If i go to the url in my browser and run it the order is as expected, however the output (JSON) seems to then revert to the order by ID (it seems to use the ID as the key) - any ideas or suggestions what I can do?

```
private _getListData(listName: string): Promise<ISPLists> {

const queryString: string = '$select=Title,ID,Created,Author/ID,Author/Title&$expand=Author/ID,Author/Title&$Orderby=SortOrder';

return this.context.spHttpClient
  .get(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('${listName}')/items`,//?${queryString}`,
  SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
  .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
    if (response.status === 404) {
      Log.error('js-display-List', new Error('List not found.'));
      return [];
    }else {
      return response.json();
    }
  });
 }
```

Comment: Is the column "sortOrder" or "SortOrder"?  odata is generally case sensitive.

Comment: sorry it is SortOrder - that part is correct and returning as expected. Its the JSON output that then changes the order

Comment: I created a similar setup to test your query, and I did not see any sort issues. Is the "SortOrder" column in the top level list?

Comment: What are the backticks for?  (`)

Comment: Just to confirm the sort issues only appear when returning as json - I think this may be by design with JSON though after some further research.

Comment: In my tests I got the correct sort order with both XML and JSON. Is your "SortOrder" column in the top level list? Here's my test where the top level list is a Task list and the lookup is a list of bikes: _api/web/lists/getbytitle('Test Task List')/items?$select=Status,Title,BikeInfo/Size,BikeInfo/Color&$expand=BikeInfo&$orderby=Status

Comment: Yeah it is in the top level. If I go to /_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Products')/items?$select=Title,ID,Created,Author/ID,Author/Title&$expand=Author/ID,Author/Title&$Orderby=SortOrder
then the returned result is in the desired order. It is only when the code return response.json(); runs does the order change to by ID